# ELKI clustering measures what do they mean?

Tags: statistics, elki

I am providing class label to the ELKI elki-bundle-0.7.1

It provides a lot of statistics such as below but i cant find info about what are they?

I know f1-measure, precision and recall however how can there be multiple measures? Aren't they supposed to be calculated according to the result of clustering?

Thank you

## Pair counting measures?

```
Jaccard 0.3851744186046512
F1-Measure 0.5561385099685204
Precision 0.6463414634146342
Recall 0.4880294659300184
Rand 0.8368055555555556
ARI 0.458537539334965

FowlkesMallows 0.5616348272664993
```

## Entropy based measures?

```
NMI Joint 0.5758289911830176
NMI Sqrt 0.7309481146561948
```

## BCubed-based measures?

```
F1-Measure 0.7033781601851384
Recall 0.6901589423648247
Precision 0.7171136653895275
```

## Set-Matching-based measures?

```
F1-Measure 0.7702702702702702
Purity 0.7916666666666667
Inverse Purity 0.7499999999999998
```

## Editing-distance measures?

```
F1-Measure 0.6312576312576313
Precision 0.6527777777777778
Recall 0.6111111111111112
```

## Gini measures?

```
Mean +-0.2958 0.703636303877176
```

Comment: there's a separate stack, namely - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439400/elki-clustering-measures-what-do-they-mean - I'm not saying anything it's just that the probability of getting response there is higher.

Comment: MonsterMMORPG: The ELKI code comes with lots and lots of literature references. **See the JavaDoc**, it has the documentation of these measures. Precision, Recall, F1 can be computed on different summaries, thus you get different precision, recall, f1, depending on what you compute them on.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse ty very much for answer. i only need clustering results. Pair counting measures is the one i should look? the one used in the literature?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse from their documentation i dont see anthing explanative : http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.7.0/doc/index.html

Comment: You need to go into the cluster evaluation package, for each of the evaluation measures. For example the class `BCubed` has the reference for the B² measures: http://dx.doi.org/10.3115/980451.980859 ... don't expect everything to be on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the ELKI documentation. We implemented many many evaluation measures. Here is an excerpt from the list on http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/RelatedPublications

Silhouette:

> P. J. Rousseeuw
>   Silhouettes: A graphical aid to the interpretation and validation of cluster analysis
>   In: Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics, Volume 20

Rand Index:

> Rand, W. M.
>   Objective Criteria for the Evaluation of Clustering Methods
>   In: Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 66 Issue 336

Fowlkes-Mallows:

> Fowlkes, E.B. and Mallows, C.L.
>   A method for comparing two hierarchical clusterings

BCubed:

> A. Bagga and B. Baldwin
>   Entity-based cross-document coreferencing using the Vector Space Model
>   In: Proc. COLING '98 Proceedings of the 17th international conference on Computational linguistics

Edit-Distance:

> Pantel, P. and Lin, D.
>   Document clustering with committees
>   In: Proc. 25th ACM SIGIR conference on Research and development in information retrieval

Entropy-based measures:

> Meilă, M.
>   Comparing clusterings by the variation of information
>   In: Learning theory and kernel machines
>
> Nguyen, X. V. and Epps, J. and Bailey, J.
>   Information theoretic measures for clusterings comparison: is a correction for chance necessary?
>   In: Proc. ICML '09 Proceedings of the 26th Annual International Conference on Machine Learning

Set-Matching purity:

> Steinbach, M. and Karypis, G. and Kumar, V.
>   A comparison of document clustering techniques
>   In: KDD workshop on text mining, 2000
>
> E. Amigó, J. Gonzalo, J. Artiles, and F. Verdejo
>   A comparison of extrinsic clustering evaluation metrics based on formal constraints
>   In: Inf. Retrieval, vol. 12, no. 5
>
> Meilă, M
>   Comparing clusterings
>   In: University of Washington, Seattle, Technical Report 418, 2002
>
> Zhao, Y. and Karypis, G.
>   Criterion functions for document clustering: Experiments and analysis
>   In: University of Minnesota, Department of Computer Science, Technical Report 01-40, 2001

C-Index:

> L. J. Hubert and J. R. Levin
>   A general statistical framework for assessing categorical clustering in free recall.
>   In: Psychological Bulletin, Vol. 83(6)

Concordant pairs:

> F. B. Baker, and L. J. Hubert
>   Measuring the Power of Hierarchical Cluster Analysis
>   In: Journal of the American Statistical Association, 70(349)
>
> F. J. Rohlf
>   Methods of comparing classifications
>   In: Annual Review of Ecology and Systematics

Davies-Bouldin:

> D. L. Davies and D. W. Bouldin
>   A Cluster Separation Measure
>   In: IEEE Transactions Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence PAMI-1(2)

PBM:

> M. K. Pakhira, and S. Bandyopadhyay, and U. Maulik
>   Validity index for crisp and fuzzy clusters
>   In: Pattern recognition, 37(3)

Variance-Ratio Criteria:

> R. B. Calinski and J. Harabasz
>   A dendrite method for cluster analysis
>   In: Communications in Statistics-theory and Methods, 3(1)

We also have DBCV, but the code is not reviewed and merged yet.

My personal recommendation is the use the **Adjusted Rand Index**, because of the nice adjustment for chance. An ARI less than 0 means the result is worse than random. With almost every other measure, even a random result will score positively.

Comment: Erich, please be kind and tell me where I can read how you adopt the "Gini measures" to measure the partitions similarity. I need a formula and a reference, if possible.

Comment: Sorry, there is no literature reference for this. I don't think you need to adopt anything, it should be the straightforward: $1/N^2 \sum_i |C_i|^2$.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Of course it is (supposed to be) the gini index of a split in a decision tree with respect to the clusters, so the weighted sum of the clusters gini each. This makes the expression a mess to set here without latex. ∑ₐ |Cₐ|/N ∑ₒ (|Cₐ∩Kₒ|/|Cₐ|)² = 1/N ∑ₐ 1/|Cₐ| ∑ₒ |Cₐ∩Kₒ|² or something like this.